# $Y = e^{-|x|}$,$ x\geq 0$ about $y = 0$. Use disk and shell method

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume bounded by $y = e^{-|x|}$, $x\geq 0$, about $y= 0$. Use disk and shell method.

Here is my integral attempt
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+0+to+1+%28y%29%28-lny%29

Multiply that by $2\pi$ and you get $\pi/2$. The correct answer is $\pi$.

Comment: I get pi/2 with disk method as well

Comment: pi * integral 0 to infinity (e^-x)^2 = 1/2

Comment: Is the answer incorrect given in my homework?

Comment: I suspect what is intended is the region below $y=e^{-|x|}$ and above the $x$-axis ($y\ge 0$). Otherwise it would have been silly to write $e^{-|x|}$.

Comment: Nope it is x>= 0. Redundant indeed though.

Comment: Then the volume is half of what they say it is.

Comment: So is my integral correct? Someone else told me the answer is 2*pi. I am so confused right now

Comment: Disk method: We get $\int_0^\infty \pi e^{-2x}\,dx$. An antiderivative is $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2x}$, the definite integral is $\pi/2$. Shells the integration is a little more unpleasant but same answer.

Comment: Cool I got the same.

Comment: So you are right, the "answer" is wrong. Presumably that's not the first time that has happened. I really do think they intended what I wrote above. By symmetry that doubles things.